# Knowing what tag UITapGestureRecognizer sends from UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm having some trouble knowing what tag my views has. I'm trying to have one method for my `UITapGestureRecognizers` and then getting the `tag` from the views. But it does not work. I've tried it with these two:

```
-(void)playGame:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr{ // Method that is getting called off my TapGestureRecognizer
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GameSegue" sender:self]; // Calling the segue
}

-(void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender{
    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender; // Try casting it to an GR
    NSLog(@"%i",tap.view.tag);

    UIView *view = (UIView *)sender; // Try casting it to an view for the tag
    NSLog(@"%i",view.tag);
}
```

But nothing works. How can I solve this problem? The casting to `UIView` just gives me `self` and not an UIView for getting an tag. so I'm getting Tag is not recognized for that instance.

Comment: Do not override `performSegue:`.

Comment: @duci9y - why not? If the OP has multiple segues from a single VC the way to differentiate is w/the segue identifier & this method. Is there a better suggestion?

Comment: @mc01 Nope, the correct place would be `prepareForSegue:`.

Comment: D'oh - right. Reading comprehension fail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should send `gesture recogniser` instead of sending `self`.Use `gr` instead of `self` as you should pass `gr` as sender and from `gr` you can get the tag of view by using `sender.view.tag`

```
-(void)playGame:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gr{ // Method that is getting called off my TapGestureRecognizer
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"GameSegue" sender:gr]; // Calling the segue
}


-(void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender{

     //In case of multiple segue its good practice to check identifier
     if([identifier isEqualToString:@"GameSegue"]){

        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender; // Try casting it to an GR
       //This will give your tag
       NSLog(@"%i",tap.view.tag);  
   }

}
```

Passing `self` means you are passing whole `view` or `viewController` in whatever context `self` is used.But as `gr` contains the view on which it is added so it will give you right tag.In your code `performSegueWithIdentifier` this line `UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = (UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;` will get view or something else so you are trying to cast wrong to geature recogniser.